# scala implementing binary tree end nodes using Option

Tags: scala

I am trying to implement end nodes in my Binary Tree.  I am wondering why this doesnt work:

// I thought that by adding Option, I can enter None as an allowed Node[T].  But neither p1 or p2 allows me to compile.  How can I make this work?

```
class Node[T](text: String, one: Option[Node[T]], two: Node[T]) {
  override def toString = "(" + one + ", " + two + ")"
}

object GenTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p1 = new Node("wait", "test", "test")
    val p2 = new Node("odd", p1, p1)

    println(p1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"test"` is not an `Option[Node[String]]]`. You need to create a leaf node and then pass it to the parent using `Some`:

```
class Node[T](text: String, one: Option[Node[T]], two: Option[Node[T]]) {
  override def toString = "(" + one + ", " + two + ")"
}

val leaf = new Node[String]("test", None, None)
val p1 = new Node("wait", Some(leaf), Some(leaf))
val p2 = new Node("wait", Some(p1), Some(p1))
```

Comment: hey, can you explain that to me?  Also this doesn't work.  It refuses to compile saying:
found : Some[Node[Nothing]] 
required: Option[Node[T]]

Comment: @user1639926 - You need to change the type of `two` to be `Option[Node[T]]` as well, see update.

Comment: i did, the error is occuring p1:

    Error:(12, 51) type mismatch;

    found   : Some[Node[Nothing]]

    required: Option[Node[T]]

        val p1 = new Node("wait", Some(leaf), Some(leaf))
                                                  ^

Comment: @user1639926 - Sorry, you also need to supply the type of `T` when creating `leaf`, updated.

Comment: why do you need to supply type T in leave but not in p1 or p2?

Answer (score 0):

First of all parameter two should also be Option[Node[T]].
Second: You need to use option if you declared it:

```
class Node[T](text: String, one: Option[Node[T]], two: Option[Node[T]]) {
  override def toString = text + " (" + one + ", " + two + ")"
}

object GenTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val p1 = new Node[String]("wait", None, None)
    val p2 = new Node("odd", Some(p1), Some(p1))

    println(p1)
  }
}
```